# docker exec messes up terminal line feeds?

Tags: terminal, docker, newlines

When I pipe the output from `docker exec` to another command, it appears to mess up my terminal's line endings.

For example:

```
$ docker exec -it foo sh -c 'echo {\"a\":\"b\",\"c\":\"d\"}' | jq
{
   "a": "b",
              "c": "d"
                      }
                       $
```

But if I then immediately run the same command, in the same terminal, on the host:

```
$ sh -c 'echo {\"a\":\"b\",\"c\":\"d\"}' | jq
{
  "a": "b",
  "c": "d"
}
```

...as expected.

If I pipe the output through `xxd`, it appears to introduce a CR character as well as the LF (0d0a, rather than 0a); it also messes up the output from `xxd`:

```
$ docker exec -i -t foo sh -c 'echo {\"a\":\"b\",\"c\":\"d\"}' | xxd
00000000: 7b22 6122 3a22 6222 2c22 6322 3a22 6422  {"a":"b","c":"d"
                                                                   00000010: 7d0d 0a
```

If I attempt to rule out docker by emitting the `\r\n` myself, it's fine:

```
$ printf "{\"a\":\"b\",\"c\":\"d\"}\r\n" | xxd
00000000: 7b22 6122 3a22 6222 2c22 6322 3a22 6422  {"a":"b","c":"d"
00000010: 7d0d 0a                                  }..
$
```

...which implies that it's `docker exec`.

Both my host and the container are running Linux. `docker info` reports `Server Version: 18.03.1-ce`. `docker -v` reports `Docker version 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40`.

What did `docker exec` do to my terminal (temporarily), and how do I fix it?

Comment: What OS are you running these commands on?

Comment: Linux; updated the question.

Comment: Thanks .. and a follow up: what is the docker image that you're running? Can you reproduce with a basic `ubuntu:latest` or similar? (I can't)

Comment: Found it: It's due to the `-t`; if someone can write an answer explaining why, that'd be sufficient.

Comment: I'm getting this behavior when spawning docker from another program, but without -t. No matter if I use --tty=false or --tty=true the behavior is exactly as you describe. No idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very interesting...

```
docker run -d ubuntu:latest sleep infinity
```

```
$ docker exec -i sharp_einstein sh -c 'echo {\"a\":\"b\",\"c\":\"d\"}' | jq
{
  "a": "b",
  "c": "d"
}
```

```
$ docker exec -it sharp_einstein sh -c 'echo {\"a\":\"b\",\"c\":\"d\"}' | jq
{
  "a": "b",
  "c": "d"
}
```

```
$ docker exec -i -t sharp_einstein sh -c 'echo {\"a\":\"b\",\"c\":\"d\"}' | jq
{
   "a": "b",
              "c": "d"
                      }
```

Separating the `-i` and `-t` allow the issue to appear... (possbly a bug?)

---

Looking at the man page for `docker exec`:

> ```
>   -t, --tty=true|false
>       Allocate a pseudo-TTY. The default is false.
> ```

Pseudo-TTYs (PTYs) allow the system to interact with you (a human)... The result is that docker allocates a new PTY for the duration of the `exec` (inside the container), and things like how to produce a newline, the terminal height and width come into play - along with a load of other things.

I can't fully explain it, but but this isn't what you want from something that is feeding into a pipeline.

---

Compare also:

```
$ docker exec -i sharp_einstein sh -c 'stty'
stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

```
$ docker exec -i -t sharp_einstein sh -c 'stty'
speed 38400 baud; line = 0;
-brkint -imaxbel
```

```
$ stty
speed 38400 baud; line = 0;
-brkint -imaxbel
```

`stty` is able to control the PTY's handling of carriage returns and newlines, though these options didn't have any effect here for me. From the man page:

> ```
>   * [-]ocrnl
>           translate carriage return to newline
>
>   * [-]onlcr
>           translate newline to carriage return-newline
> ```

---

There are similar observations with `sst -t`, for example: [stair-stepping when using a pty (through ssh) and piping to more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10483525/1347519)

Comment: Interesting. There's no difference between `-i -t` and `-it` on my installation; they're both broken.

Comment: Also: why is the behaviour of the pseudo-tty affecting the behaviour of my terminal's tty? `jq` runs in my tty.

Comment: Unfortunately that falls into my "_I can't fully explain it_"... I can at best offer a hypothesis that `docker` is playing with your local PTY to make things more "_transparent_"... I might dig into some sources later...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with "-n" on "echo **-n**" like :

```
$ docker exec -it upbeat_mendeleev sh -c 'echo {\"a\":\"b\",\"c\":\"d\"}' | jq .
{
   "a": "b",
              "c": "d"
                      }


$ docker exec -it upbeat_mendeleev sh -c 'echo -n {\"a\":\"b\",\"c\":\"d\"}' | jq .
{
  "a": "b",
  "c": "d"
}
```

Comment: I'm not actually using `echo`; this is just an example for the repro. So I can't add `-n`.